# How to Get authentication, without user intervention

Tags: authentication, google-oauth

I am developing in php and I manage a Google calendars (insert, modify and delete events from a calendar).

Following the examples of Google, always asks me to verify the account validation Google, how I can prevent this?

The example used is: [google calendar example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing and using the oauth token that Google sends you on the first authentication?

Comment: Yes, but if I log back perdir me to verify the credentials.
I want to leave credentials in the application source code (php). I think this is only possible with Google Bussines Account: (

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to access Google's APIs you need an access token. To get access tokens without the user's interaction you will need a refresh token.

Just set the OAuth 2.0 'access_type' parameter to 'offline' in the authorization request. This will result in your application obtaining a refresh token the first time your application exchanges an authorization code for a user. You can then use the refresh token to obtain access tokens without the user being present in the browser. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer for more info.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks! With this and other things gave the "Service Account" and solved. Greetings.